# extract elements from xml document

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document in which I want to extract every 10 elements. I used this code to extract the last 10 elements, but the idea is to get the next 10 ones just before them, I can't use pagination with linq since I get the whole document:

```
slideView.ItemsSource = 
    (from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("album")     
     orderby (int)channel.Element("catid") descending 
     select new onair
     {
         title = (string)channel.Element("name"),
         photo = (string)channel.Element("picture")
     }).Take(10);
```

any ideas please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try .Skip(10).Take(10) towards the end of your query.

Comment: Hello, ok it does the job but it will change the old list by another one with the other 10 elemnts besides i want to make that dynamicly which means every time when pushing the button the older list still and we get the next 10 ones and so one. thanks :)